# authenticate user using devise in custom controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, devise

I'm using rails 3 and devise and I would like to have a SecurityController where I call methods like sign_in_user or reset_password which will be a post passing in parameters like username and password to it.

I know I could use before_filter :authenticate_user! but I would like to authenticate myself. If the authentication is successful then I would like for that user to sign_in.

Reason I do this is because I have an iphone app which depends on authenticating to the web app to use the app.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't had reason to do this myself yet, but if you read the "Configuring Controllers" section at https://github.com/plataformatec/devise, it show how you can create a custom controller that extends `Devise::SessionsController`, and then point your authentication routing to that controller.  I think that is what you are asking how to do -- correct?

To quote from the page...

If the customization at the views level is not enough, you can customize each controller by following these steps:

1) Create your custom controller, for example a Admins::SessionsController:

```
class Admins::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
end
```

2) Tell the router to use this controller:

```
devise_for :admins, :controllers => { :sessions => "admins/sessions" }
```

3) And since we changed the controller, it won’t use the "devise/sessions" views, so remember to copy "devise/sessions" to "admin/sessions".

Comment: I only want to customize 2 methods....authenticate and reset password. Is there a way for me to do this without extending the whole sessions controller and rewriting other methods

Comment: As I said, I haven't tried extending making a controller extension like this, but I'd be very surprised if you have to rewrite anything.  The whole point of extending any kind of class is to inherit the normal behavior of that class, and then add or modify as needed.  You should not have to rewrite anything, just override what you need to change.  If you need to invoke the default behavior at some point within an overridden method, use `super`.

Comment: I can confirm what Steve has said.  If you decide you want to customize a controller and include the lines of code that Steve has suggested (as well as copying over the necessary views), then Devise will work exactly the same even if you leave these custom controllers empty.  Any action you don't specifically override just defaults back to Devise's built-in action.  Any action you __do__ override can just be add-ons to the original action by calling `super`